# After upgrading my project from dotnet 3.1 to dotnet 7, the controller action route returns 404

Tags: c#, .net

if action attrubite [Route] is present it sees the path but if not it returns 404.

My Startup;

```cs
app
    .UseRouting() // Routing
    .UseCors() // Cors
    .UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{lang=en}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "dynamicHtmlPages",
            pattern: "{lang=en}/pages/{slug}/{controller=Pages}/{action=Index}");

        endpoints.MapHub<RealTimeHub>("/realtimehub");
        endpoints.MapHub<RealTimeRequestsHub>("/realtimerequestshub");
    });
```